# Swift/Obj-C bridging header not found/failed to import

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

So I have an Objective-C codebase that I'm trying to add Swift files to. I created my bridging header which *mostly* works but run into issues when importing certain classes. I have had success using classes from my Project-Bridging-Header.h in my Swift files and had success using my Swift classes by importing Project-Swift.h to my Obj-c classes. However, importing certain classes cause file not found errors. These classes that cause issues are just obj-c classes I've created.

The errors I'm receiving are:
'Project-Swift.h' file not found, and Failed to import bridging header 'path/to/header'.

I have previously seen these headers work and have used swift code in objective c and vice versa successfully. It's just when I import certain objective-c classes to my bridging header that it complains.

Has anyone experienced this or know what might be happening?

Comment: Where are the classes that aren't found located, and what are the import statements you are using?

Comment: My Bridging header is located at `$(SRCROOT)/Project/Supporting Files/Project-Bridging-Header.h` and the swift header is automatically generated, so wherever Xcode puts it I guess. I'm using import statements like `#import "MyClass.h", which works for certain classes but not others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem and it turned out that I had a cricular reference where my Swift class used my OjbC class which in turn used Swift class.

I resolved it by using froward declaration in ObjC header and importing Project-Swift.h in .m

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have checked out this guide, [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-ID0), otherwise you might want to take a look first to see whether the guidelines are helpful to your situation. You may want to double check particularly for some special case like [Referencing a Swift Class or Protocol in an Objective-C Header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID158).

If that doesn't work, double check whether those classes in question are set for the correct target(s). And clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was helpful, though I've accepted @juhan_h's answer as his was more specific in answering my question.